# Changing the user object for the current user in Symfony logs me out

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following code:

```
public function editAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    // Get the user
    $user2 = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('OpinionsUserBundle:User')
        ->findOneById($user->id);

    echo $user->email . '<br>'; // Echo me@example.org
    echo $user2->email . '<br>'; // Echo me@example.org

    $user2->email = 'blah';

    echo $user->email; // Echoes blah
    die();
}
```

So I know that Doctrine must be doing something with references. The problem is I have a form where the user can change their name and email, but if the email is already in use I want to show an error. However, Symfony binds data to the user object when I check validation, so somehow the session is being updated with the new user object, logging me out or changing my user.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Your example proved that these are not references to the same object (you've changed email of $user2 and $user 's email stayed the same as it was). Here is good example how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812510/symfony2-how-to-modify-the-current-users-entity-using-a-form . All the best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was refreshing the user model (returning it to it's original state) if my form validation failed.

```
// Reset to default values or else it will get saved to the session
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->refresh($user);
```